Compose navigation re-instantiates WebView inside a screen when having NavigationBar
I'm currently testing compose navigation following the docs. Consider having two screens called Home and Web. The navigation is being used as follow:
@Composable
fun ButtonNavigationApp() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    Scaffold(
       bottomBar = { BottomNavigationBar(navController) }
    ) { innerPadding ->
       NavHost(
           navController = navController,
           startDestination = "Home"
       ) {
           addHomeScreen()
           addWebScreen()
       }
    }
}

Home screen:
fun NavGraphBuilder.addHomeScreen() {
    composable("Home") {
        Text("Home is here")
    }
}

Web screen:
fun NavGraphBuilder.addWebScreen() {
    composable("Web") {
        AndroidView(
            onReset = {}, // Add to reuse the view as documentation says.
            factory = { context ->
                WebView(context).apply {
                    // Initializing web-view here
                }
            },
            update = { it.loadUrl("google.com") }
        )
    }

}

Navigation Bar:
@Composable
fun BottomNavigationBar(navController: NavHostController) {
    ...
    
    NavigationBar {

        NavigationBarItem(
         ...
           onclick = { 
               navController.navigate("Home") {
                   popUpTo(navController.graph.startDestinationId) { saveState = true }
                   launchSingleTop = true
                   restoreState = true
               }
           }
         ...
        )

        NavigationBarItem(
         ...
           onclick = { 
               navController.navigate("Web") {
                   popUpTo(navController.graph.startDestinationId) { saveState = true }
                   launchSingleTop = true
                   restoreState = true
               }
           }
         ...
        )
    }
}


Problem: When navigating from Home to Web screen, the url loads as expected. When clicking on Home and then clicking on Web, the url is being loaded again (although view models are surviving).
I checked and found out that the compose screen is being recreated, hence the web view is recreated again. How can I force the navigation to not create another instance of the web view?
